# What happened to this answer?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure if anyone else has been following the question [Does Stress reset to zero between sessions in Maid RPG?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/does-stress-reset-to-zero-between-sessions-in-maid-rpg)

I upvoted and commented on an answer which has since disappeared.  I suspect that it was deleted by the author, which leads me to question why.

I (personally) felt that it was a good answer, and I hate to see it be deleted.  My inclination is that the poster may have felt unwelcome, in which case I am disheartened, as this was a new poster.

Is there any way we can reach out to this person and ask why?

Comment: I'm afraid I may have been overly critical of the answer to that question of mine. My comment, "Have you thought of becoming an RPG blogger?" was meant self-deprecatingly, as I'm an RPG blogger myself. In retrospect, a more encouraging tone would have been appropriate, and I feel bad for making a new user feel unwelcome.

Answer (score 4):

That user emailed and asked to be deleted.

You might want to consider how you're treating your new users -- particularly since IMHO that was an excellent answer from a user that *might* have become a useful contributor to the site. This is especially important for sites that need to grow and find an audience.

Comment: Jeff, I am very sorry to hear that. I tried to be supportive from the start, but maybe I only stirred things up more. Politics is tough in real life, let alone the internet :\

Comment: I'm also sorry to hear that. I mistook the newbie for an established user, as he had a user icon, some reputation and badges. I disagree as to the quality of the answer, but should I have been more constructive in reply. It would be good policy to take an encouraging tone with new users to help them become established.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate, we need to be a lot more friendly. Not that we should treat our established users poorly either. I wish he'd stuck around a little longer though, there's very little anyone can do if a guy goes from first scuffle straight to deletion; by the time the question came to mod attention the guy was apparently back on the turnip truck.

Comment: I fear this is a bad trend we need to reverse. I've been involved with online communities since the late 70s, and It'd be a stretch to put this one in the "friendly to n00bs" category. But, you've seen my posts here in Meta on this before.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was by @sunfall.  You can try contacting him via the comments on your question or in chat and asking him to undelete. There was a long comment thread on the question that would indicate he felt chased off by @JonathanDrain. Warning to all three of you, play nice.